# How to select parameters from different tables in one column sql?

Tags: sql, talend

I have two tables with name of countries. I need to do select, which will show first countries names from first table and then from second table.

table1:
USA
Germany

table2:
Spain
Ukraine

Expected result from select:

```
USA
Germany
Spain
Ukraine
```

Comment: So is this an ordering question or a union question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Country from table1
union
select Country from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below

```
with cte as(
select country_name,
row_number()over(order by country_name) as rn  from table1
union all
select country_name,-1 from table2
) select country_name from cte order by rn desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a common field you can use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID=table.ID;
```